# How to remove word suggestion bar in text messages in ios10?

Tags: ios

How do you remove the word suggestion grey bar that is above the keyboard? On the previous ios you were able to pull it down. That option is no longer avaliable in ios10.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off "Predictive" in Settings --> General --> Keyboard.

Comment: I want predictive, just not the grey bar.

Comment: It's the only way I've found to hide the bar. Still seems to predict words for me in pop-up bubbles based on best guess of what I'm typing, which is fine, but I find the bar with ever-changing suggested words distracting as hell when I'm typing.